# didBegin not detecting contact between two SKSpriteNodes

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, skphysicsbody

In my didMove function I say `physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self` and at the top of the class I inherit from `SKPhysicsContactDelegate`. I add a SKSpriteNode with a physics body initialized like so:

```
        alien.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: alienSize)
        alien.physicsBody!.affectedByGravity = false
```

I then define the physics body of another node that makes contact with the alien in the same way. When they make contact, the two elements do collide into each other, but for some reason `didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact)` is not called, meaning that even when I say:

```
    func didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
        print("\n\nContact!\n\n")
    }
```

nothing prints out when the two elements make contact. Any ideas of what I need to look at to try and fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the rep yet to post comments, so I have to put my thoughts in an answer.  Have you tried running your code on an actual device?  There are issues with the simulator not properly creating a physics body from some images.  One work around is to compile for iOS version 12.x and running in a simulator set with that version of iOS. But you won't be able to take advantage of iOS features in 13 and above.